# Vimeo video doesn't work

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to get a Vimeo video working, but the video is still just black screen. What is wrong?

```
<video src="//player.vimeo.com/video/20802032?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=990033" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></video>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What _you_ are doing wrong is putting that URL in a `video` element … the URL delivers a complete HTML document, so to embed it use an `iframe`.

Comment: Okay, but with iframe it also doesn't work... @CBroe

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you should use the embeddable iframe rather than your current attempt.  Vimeo provides this code for every video you own or otherwise are able to (are permitted to) embed.

Another way to get the correct embed code is to use their [oEmbed](http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed) endpoint.  For example, this json is retrieved for your video:

http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http%3A//vimeo.com/20802032

In case you don't care to click on that, here's what's is served at that url:

```
{
   "type":"video",
   "version":"1.0",
   "provider_name":"Vimeo",
   "provider_url":"https:\/\/vimeo.com\/",
   "title":"Motion Graphics Reel 2011",
   "author_name":"timurfrost",
   "author_url":"http:\/\/vimeo.com\/timurfrost",
   "is_plus":"1",
   "html":"<iframe src=\"\/\/player.vimeo.com\/video\/20802032\" width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" frameborder=\"0\" title=\"Motion Graphics Reel 2011\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen><\/iframe>",
   "width":1280,
   "height":720,
   "duration":78,
   "description":"Motion Graphics Reel by Timur Frost",
   "thumbnail_url":"http:\/\/b.vimeocdn.com\/ts\/161\/363\/161363406_1280.jpg",
   "thumbnail_width":1280,
   "thumbnail_height":720,
   "video_id":20802032
}
```

As you see, there's no reason to guess the correct way to embed the video.  Using only the video url and knowledge of this data service, you can submit an http request and retrieve the officially sanctioned embed html, as well as a host of other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `iframe` instead.

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ngDtc/1/)

Example from fiddle:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/20802032?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=990033" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```